# Unable to extract Model Data Using created_at in rails 2 application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

```
@versions = Version.find_all_by_created_at(2015-05-07)
@versions = []
```

datatype for created_at(datetime)

Please i want extract data by passing only date to a model .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is simple
If you want to do it for the current date then you can just use Date.today

```
Version.where(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)
```

Otherwise as @davidesantangelo has mentioned that is fine, except using parsed "date" variable, you can use "date.beginning_of_day"
e.g.

```
selectDate = Date.parse('2015-05-07')

Version.where(created_at: selectDate.beginning_of_day..selectDate.end_of_day)
```

That will form query like this:

```
SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" 
WHERE ("versions"."created_at" 
BETWEEN '2015-04-28 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-04-28 23:59:59.999999')
```

And without "beginning_of_day" it will have query like

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
WHERE ("users"."created_at" 
BETWEEN '2015-04-28' AND '2015-04-28 23:59:59.999999')
```

So I would prefer it with beginning_of_day.

Answer (score 0):

Created at is a datetime so it would be very specific. You need to search within the same day

```
date = Date.parse('2015-05-07')
Version.where(created_at: date..date.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
date = Date.parse('2015-05-07')
```

and then

```
Version.where("created_at <= ? AND created_at >= ?", date + 1, date - 1)
```